# Minitest for testing presence and allow_nil for the same attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, validation, minitest

I want to test a model attribute where it has presence as true, but also allow nil value. How can I test this? I made an example bellow:

```
# Person model
belongs_to :city

validates :city_id, presence: true, :allow_nil => true
```

I was trying to test with:

```
test "should permit nil for city_id" do
  @person.city_id = nil
  assert @person.valid?
end
```

What I got in console:

> Expected false to be truthy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The test was failing because it was missing a argument in belongs_to:

```
# Person model
belongs_to :city, optional: true

validates :city_id, presence: true, :allow_nil => true
```

The argument Optional allows nil value to foreign key.